# Firebase .on not working with authentication

Tags: php, firebase, firebase-security, jwt

**UPDATE**

I was able to at least get the client side code to work with authentication using `firebase-simple-login.js` and `auth.login('anonymous')`. Server side (ie "write") still does not work.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION**

I am creating an app with Firebase integration and simply need to secure my Firebase data. Being able to delete everything if you know my Firebase URL and where to look without any authentication is obviously less than ideal.

I am not trying to log my users in (or at least not in the traditional sense), I just want to make sure that there is SOME SORT of authentication going on when I read and write from my Firebase data. I have spent hours on this and cannot seem to make it work (so much for "easy").

First, my Firebase security rules - simple

```
{
    "rules": {
      ".read" : "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null"
    }
}
```

I am pushing to Firebase from server side code and reading the results client side. This is a simple polling app - poll responses are pushed to Firebase in the following format: `clients\ClientA\polls\POLLID(random)\RandomDataID(from Firebase)\Response Data`. I am using  [firebase/php-jwt](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt) to generate my server side JWT:

```
    <?php

class generateFirebaseToken {
    public static function generate(array $data = array())
    {
        $key = 'FIREBASE SECRET KEY';
        $token = array(
            'iss' => 'https://example.com',
            'iat' => time()
        );
        // Add additional data to token
        $token = array_merge($token, $data);
        $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);

        return $jwt;
    }
}
```

I am then pushing data to Firebase with the following code. There are several variables from the user's session included. This uses a class I wrote that prepares a CURL request for Firebase. Everything works fine if I remove the `auth != null` from the Firebase rules. Otherwise, nothin':

```
$fbData = array(
            'name' => "{$this->user->first_name} {$this->user->last_name}",
            'answer' => $fbAnswer,
            'gravatar' => Gravatar::src($this->user->email)
        );
        $token = generateFirebaseToken::generate();
        $fb = new fireBase("clients/{$this->client->nickname}/polls/{$poll->uniquid}.json?auth=$token", $fbData);
        $fb->execute('POST');
```

Source of $fb->execute()

```
public function execute($method)
    {
        $data_string = json_encode($this->data);

        $ch = curl_init($this->root . $this->path); // http://myapp.firebaseio.com/
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string))
        );

        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        return $result;
    }
```

Client side also does not work. I retrieve a JWT by performing a `$.getJSON` request to my server side code and pass it on to Firebase. It seems to authenticate correctly but then I receive the error `FIREBASE WARNING: on() or once() for /clients/exampleclient/polls/FdV4RM9LHcoB7U7W failed: Error: permission_denied: Client doesn't have permission to access the desired data.`. Here is the client side code:

```
    $.getJSON('/secure/jwt-token', function(json) {
        jwtToken = json.token;
        launchFirebase(jwtToken);
    });
function launchFirebase(token)
{
    var fb = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/clients/exampleclient/polls/' + pollID);
    fb.auth(token, function(e) {
        if(e) {
            alert('Authentication error : ' + e);
        } else {
            alert('Authenticated'); // Alert shows, so I assume authenticated
            fb.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
                // do stuff
                // Error occurs here.
            });
        }
    });
}
```

I am assuming I am missing something simple here, perhaps I do not understand how to use JWT.. whatever the case, any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HOURS** of wasted effort but I finally found the problem, hopefully this helps someone else new to using Firebase. Also goes to show that if you're working on the same issue for hours, take a break and the fog will begin to clear.

Okay, the problem was -- of course -- simple. I was using the `firebase/php-jwt` library. I had everything right EXCEPT for the fact that I did not add `'d'` to the token data array - **THIS IS WHERE `auth` COMES FROM.** So, my security rules was checking for `auth`, missing because I did not add `d` to my token.

Here is the fixed code:

```
$key = 'YOUR-SECURITY-KEY';
        $token = array(
            'iss' => 'https://EXAMPLE.com',
            'iat' => time(),
            'd' => array(
                'foo' => 'bar' // THIS GIVES YOU THE AUTH VARIABLE!!!!!
            )
        );
        // Add additional data to token
        $token = array_merge($token, $data);
        $jwt = JWT::encode($token, $key);

        return $jwt;
```

If you write code for people to plug into a service, as in this case, PLEASE provide better documentation. It seems too often that such things are just entirely omitted, perhaps because the developer should just know intrinsically? I finally discovered the answer reading the docs for making a token WITHOUT the use of a helper library (like this one).

Comment: When utilizing the Firebase SDKs, if you try to create a token without any contents in auth, it throws an Error. You've essentially circumvented the check here by using PHP's JWT. Considering that you are creating a token without a helper library, and it's shown it the docs for creating a token without a helper library, I'm a bit confused on your expectation for how this should be documented?

Comment: I'm sorry but it appeared to me that I WAS using a helper library. When you click on PHP under Helper Libraries it goes to firebase/php-jwt. So it's understandable to assume that this is a helper library.